# I have a tkinter entry box in python but I can't get the input from it into my code?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my code below :

```
from tkinter import *
login = Tk()

username_1 = Entry()
username_1.pack(side=TOP)
input_username = login.username_1.get("1.0", END)
username = input_username
loginInfo = {"user1": "blue", "user2": "yellow", "user3": "green"}
if username in loginInfo:
    print('Username correct!')

login.mainloop()
```

This is my error:

```
'AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'username_1'':
```

Comment: When creating the Entry, you must give it the login in parameters like so: `username_1 = Entry(login)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide information about what your code is supposed to do?

If you just want to avoid this error - change line 6 for this:

```
input_username = username_1.get()
```

Comment: By the way, the syntax `.get("1.0", END)` is for a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1):

When you create widgets, you are creating children of the root window. However, these children are not *attributes* of the root window. Thus, `login.username_1` is invalid, just as the error is telling you.

In this specific case, the widget is simply `username_1` (eg: `input_username = username_1.get("1.0", END)`). However, even that won't work for the following reasons:

- the `get` method of the entry doesn't take arguments. You need to do `username_1.get()`.
- you are calling `get` about one millisecond after the entry has been created, well before the user has a chance to enter anything.

With a GUI toolkit you can't think of your program running linearly from top to bottom. Instead, you set things up to initially appear, and then you need to write functions that respond to events such as key presses and button clicks. For example, you might want to create a button with the label "Login" that calls a function to check for valid credentials. It would be within that function that you call the `get()` method.